# FullCalendar Make ButtonText Dynamic

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e30F2.png]

I am new to FullCalendar. Now how can I make the buttons on the header that will look like in the picture above?

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDate()
{
    jQuery('.fc-today-button').text(calendar.fullCalendar('getDate').format('MMM YYYY'));   
    jQuery('.fc-next-button').text((calendar.fullCalendar('getDate')).add(1,'M').format('MMM') + ' >');
    jQuery('.fc-prev-button').text('< ' + (calendar.fullCalendar('getDate')).add(-1,'M').format('MMM'));
    jQuery('.fc-nextYear-button').text((calendar.fullCalendar('getDate')).add(1,'Y').format('YYYY') + ' >');
    jQuery('.fc-prevYear-button').text('< ' +(calendar.fullCalendar('getDate')).add(-1,'Y').format('YYYY'));
}

jQuery('.fc-button').click(function()
{
    getDate();      
})
```

I was able to solved my problem using the codes above.